# What is the best way to design endpoints for a restful application?

Tags: rest, api-design, backend

I am a backend developer and I am writing a restful application. I have a question about how best to design the endpoints.

I have a database table that stores values (I just provided an example)

```
|id (int)|A (bool)| B (bool)|
| 1      |   0    |    0    |
| 2      |   0    |    1    |
| 3      |   1    |    1    |
```

Business logic:

1. If A=0 B=0 then we consider "**no action**"
2. If A=0 B=1 then we consider that "**the action has begun**"
3. If A=1 B=1 then we consider "**action ended**"

How can I do it better?

### Style 1

Make one endpoint `[PUT] /action` to the body of which I will expect from the frontender

```js
{"id": int, "A": bool, "B": bool}
```

In this case, I'm shifting to the front-end the writing of the logic for separating the use cases of the endpoint

### Style 2

Make a separate endpoint for each business function

1. `[POST] /action/begin`
2. `[POST] /action/end`
3. `[DELETE] /action`

In this case I expect only the `id` of the object from the front, and I will fill in A and B myself

Comment: Your database table (and it's corresponding JSON) are *implementation details.*  There is some benefit to hiding those details via Style 2.

Comment: But there is no "best" way.  There is only that way that best meets your specific needs.

Comment: The semantics of your application should be reflected in the api, but with this foo bar example there are no semantics to inform the style

Comment: It's hard to opine without knowing the specifics but it seems to me that Style 2 is *almost* intuitively obvious while Style 1 is completely obscure and would require documentation to understand. So my instinct is to prefer Style 2. Style 2 also lets you use HTTP nodes (e.g. firewall, proxy) to filter, restrict, or route requests by path or verb. With Style 1 it would not be very natural to do the same.